# Local variables in parallel Jenkinsfile task

Tags: variables, jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

```
    tasks = [:]

    availableNodes.each { nodeName ->

        final def ProfilesForThisNode = getProfilesForNode(args.Profiles, nodeName)

        if (ProfilesForThisNode) {

            tasks[nodeName] = {

                node(nodeName) {

                    try {
                        final def workspace = path("$path123")

                        ws("$workspace") {
                            stage("$nodeName transmission") {

                                kw_job = "some_name"

                                if (isWindows()) {
                                    if (!kw_job.contains("Windows")) {
                                        kw_job = kw_job + "_Windows"
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    if(!kw_job.contains("Linux")) {
                                        kw_job = kw_job + "_Linux"
                                    }
                                }
                                echo kw_job

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (hudson.model.Run.RunnerAbortedException e) {
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    parallel(tasks)
```

I use this code (part of a Jenkinsfile) twice: Once on a Windows Slave and once on a Linux Slave of Jenkins.

I think it is pretty obvious what I want: One echo with "some_name_Windows" and one with "some_name_Linux", but I get something like "some_name_Windows" and "some_name_Windows_Linux".

How do I use variables locally on one slave during two (or more) parallel processes with a Jenkinsfile pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare a variable without the `def` keyword, it has global scope. Change it to

```
def kw_job = "some_name"
```

and you should be good.